# Clicking to get the next page with postback

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I am trying to take a screenshot from page 1 and page 2 from a ASP page with a postback.
I am trying to use casperjs to access the first page and save a screenshot, then click next and take a screenshot from the second page.

My code works well with some other sites, but this one is giving me a hard time.

My code is as follows:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({logLevel: "debug", verbose: true });
casper.start('http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies', function() {
    this.capture('Step1.png');
    this.wait(5000, function() {
        this.click('#ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_dvwListItems_PGB a.dxp-button.dxp-bi:nth-of-type(1)');
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.capture('Step2.png');
    this.echo('finished');
    this.exit();
});
```

debug info:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.d58098f8a7f0ff5a206e7f15442a6b30.pt.html#_=1415538373180&count=none&id=twitter-widget-0&lang=pt&original_referer=http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies&size=m&text=S L O T - Ofertas de Emprego&url=http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to /home/netlisbon/test/Step1.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to /home/netlisbon/test/Step1.png
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 1559ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3 http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3: done in 1560ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 5000ms.
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: #ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_dvwListItems_PGB a.dxp-button.dxp-bi:nth-of-type(1)
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: #ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_dvwListItems_PGB a.dxp-button.dxp-bi:nth-of-type(1)
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: #ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_dvwListItems_PGB a.dxp-button.dxp-bi:nth-of-type(1)
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 6571ms
finished
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to /home/netlisbon/test/Step2.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to /home/netlisbon/test/Step2.png
```

However, both screenshots show the same page...
I tried to click on the other arrow to go to the last page, but I get the same result.

Can someone find out what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The postback functionality is JavaScript and it doesn't trigger a navigation step. But since CasperJS' steps only wait for the current navigation step to finish, the script finishes before the next "page" is loaded.

You will have to either wait a static amount of time after the click

```
this.wait(5000, function() { this.click('selector'); });
this.wait(5000);
```

or even better, you keep track on which page you are and wait for the specific page to appear:

```
var page = 1;
this.wait(5000, function() {
    this.click('selector');
    page++;
});
this.waitFor(function check(){
    return this.fetchText(".dxp-summary").indexOf("Page " + page + " of ") === 0;
}, function then() {
    // screenshot or whatever
});
```